# Why some felds of model class are not created in MongoDb?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

**Problem**

I am new to mongodb application and I am using spring boot and mongodb as a database.

I wanted to know

> Why some fields of model class are not created in mongodb.

Below is my model class

```
@Document
public class User extends LoginUser {
public static final String OBJECT_KEY = "APPUSER";

@Id
private String id;
 @Field
private String[] imageIds;
@Field
private String concerns;
@Field
private String summary;
@Field
private String likings;
@Field
private String occupation;
@Field
private String religion;
@Field
private String education;
@Field
private String height;
@GeoSpatialIndexed(type = GeoSpatialIndexType.GEO_2DSPHERE)
@Field
private double[] location;
@Field
private INTERESTS[] interests;
@Field
private String fcmId;
@Field
private List connections;
@Field
private List declined;
@Field
private List pending;
```

**Output Expected**

User Model with all fields in the document

**Output Shown**

User Model with *id*,location,name and username.

i.e the fields where annotation is marked in my code.

Comment: You are missing @Field annotations.

Comment: @RafalG. Okay Thank you

Comment: @RafalG. Still the Fields in Mongo are not shown after doing the changes.See the edit

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why you need the @Field annotation there.

here's an example of a pojo (from my project) what works:

```
@Document(collection = "clients")
public class ClientData {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private double bearing;
    private double latitude;
    private double velocity;
    private double longitude;
    private LocationBearerType clientDataType = CAR;
    private Boolean standby;
    private long timestamp;
```

and dont forget to state a collection name (in the document annotation)